# Is there a convenient way to display values in a node graph?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

This is probably a long shot.
Is there any Add-On or common method people use to display values within the node graph?

It would make understanding what I'm doing easier if I had a simple way of displaying said info.

If there was a way to "Promote" the value to being a variable I can see in a list.
(I vaguely remember "promoting" values from using Houdini like 5 years ago)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can see the values of the Viewer Node in the Spreadsheet.

Just connect the output of the node to the Viewer Node.
[image]

[image]